# Rails localhost on mobile without any styling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking

I am running the rails server using, rails server -b 0.0.0.0 so i can access the local server on my mobile too. Though it is accessible from my mobile but it is just showing the html part without any css or js. Can anyone tell me why ?

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to know for sure without anymore info, but could it be because your phone isn't connected to the internet and you're using/linking to some external libraries which then naturally requires internet connection?